# передача данных с формы в pivot таблицу laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день! Недавно начал изучать ларавел и возникла проблема (в интернете ничего подобного не нашел либо не правильно составлял запрос)
есть форма для добавления юзера(админка)
[image: форма]

в поле Категория выбираются привилегии для него.
Ниже показано как я добавляю пользователя в базу

```
User::create([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);
```

В моделях для User и Role установлены отношения м-м 
в бд есть смешанная таблица по внешним ключам к юзеру и роли.
Как по выбранной категории установить права для только что созданного пользователя? нужно в смежную таблицу записать id пользователя и id роли
[image: роли]

прошу помочь реализовать это, либо посоветовать материал который поможет мне с этим

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае у вас связь многие ко многим, всё что нужно сделать, это:
1) Прописать связь пользователя с ролью в модели пользователя:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

2) Аналогично делаем с ролями:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

3) Потом после создания пользователя привязываем к нему роль:

```
$user = User::create([
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
]);
$user->roles()->attach($request->input('role_id')); // Или как там у вас называется поле.
```

Так же к связям добавил метод `withTimestamps`чтобы так же записывалась дата как у вас на скриншоте.

[Информация по созданию реляции](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

[Информация по сохранению](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: В моделях у меня все прописано так же как и вы написали, а за attach спасибо, почитаю за него